# Как отработать событие кнопки в Notification на андроид?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-уведомления

У меня есть PUSH уведомление с кнопкой. Не могу сделать так что бы при нажатии на кнопку вызывался метод.

```
    Intent iOK= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent piOK = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, iOK, 0);

 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHENEL_1_ID)
                .addAction(R.raw.weewqwqe, "OK", piOK)
                .build();
 notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Класс MainActivity содержит метод a(){ } помогите вызвать его

Answer (score 0):

Строка: `PendingIntent piOK = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, iOK, 0);` Говорит что именно вы будете вызывать. Читать [здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/204-urok-119-pendingintent-flagi-requestcode-alarmmanager.html). Соответственно метод `getBroadcast()`говорит о том что по нажатии кнопки будет запущен `BroadcastReceiver` указанный в `Intent`. У вас же указано `Activity`, исходя из выше сказанного `getBroadcast()` меняем на `getActivity()` и в intent кладём iOK.putExtra("command", "playA").

в Activity, в onResume() пишем:

```
if("playA".equals(intent.getStringExtra("command"))){
    a();
}
```

UPD: Ещё один по нотификациям: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/510-urok-185-notifications-rezhimy-otkrytiya-activity.html.
Гуглите, гугл полон информации.